# How can i take n number of input in an array in javascript, python

Tags: javascript, python-3.x

I want to take an user input that determins the number of inputs desired to take & input that number of inputs . For example if i need to enter 5 inputs ,the user would get a prompt asking what number of inputs you want to enter & if i log it and continue the the user gets another prompt asking the inputs

Comment: [This page describing HackerRank challenges](https://codeburst.io/solving-challenges-from-hackerrank-using-javascript-part-3-9ba247163e8e) explains the technique you're describing.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?  And please narrow your question down to a specific language/framework since it will greatly impact the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In javascript

```
let numbersOfInputs = 1 * prompt('Enter the total numbers of input',0); 
let inputAsArray = [] ;
for(let index = 0;index < numbersOfInputs;index += 1){
let temp = 1 * prompt(`Enter the value for inputAsArray[${index}]`,0);
inputAsArray.push(temp);
};
console.log(inputAsArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this for python and use the list as you want

```
lst = [] 
n = int(input("Enter number of elements : ")) 
for i in range(0, n): 
    ele = int(input()) 
    lst.append(ele) # adding the element 

print(lst)  #lst will contain all user inputs
```

For Javascript

```
var lst = [];
var n = prompt("Enter number of elements : ");
var ele;
for(let i = 0; i < n; i++){
    ele = prompt("");
    lst.push(ele); # adding the element 
}
console.log(lst); #lst will contain all user inputs
```